# SQL how to get 3 dates records ?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I got a demand that  I have to select 3 dates from the DB, but the datetime field of my table records are not in sequence.  How do I write the **SQL** to get 3 dates' records  greater than today?

thanks

Comment: i need 3 date's records ,not just 3 records

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need. Just use `GETDATE()` to get current date.

```
SELECT TOP 3 dateColumn from myTable where dateColumn > GETDATE()
```

Comment: top 3  only give 3 records ,but what i need is 3 dates' records ~

Comment: @user2515229 If you would have provided your table structure, then I would have made the query to work exactly as you requested. But I assume you can handle modifying the query and changing the column and table to those that you use.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 3 * from <tablename> where yourdateColumn > getdate() order by desc
```